# What is the purpose of the airplane icon in my system tray?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

My Windows 7 system tray has an airplane icon that I am not familiar with.  When I hover over it, the tooltip says "Mode: High Performance":

[image]

If I right-click on it, the menu says:

[image]

Does anyone know the purpose of this icon/program?

Comment: That is not part of windows, it is some app installed by you or your computer's manufacturer.

Comment: Probably something to do with your wireless card and "Airplane Mode". If you can provide details of your PC (make/model) and your wireless card (make/model) you may get a more accurate answer.

Comment: I built the PC and did all of the software installations.  It may be part of one of the programs I installed -- possibly one of my motherboard's drivers.  My PC doesn't have a wireless card.  Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode was not introduced until W8 and its icon is different, it must be some third party program.

[image]

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-is-airplane-mode)